# Update Manager warning: lost interfaces (for a driver)

Tags: drivers, update-manager, scanner

Due to a daily update, I lost my Epson scanner facility.

I run under 14.04.
Updating at about Nov 6, 2005 05:15 (GMT +1) by the ordinary Update Manager, I got the warnings

```
"/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdb" lost interfaces: ("org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block") 
"/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/EPSON_Storage_564357593030313879" lost interfaces: ("org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Drive") 
"/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/EPSON_Storage_564357593030313879" has new interfaces: ("org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Drive") 
"/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdb" has new interfaces: ("org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block")
```

They were many times repeated. Similar warnings might have been issued.

Since then, my Epson Stylus SX100 scanner is not anymore recognised.

Any suggestion or solution?

Answer (score 0):

- A few hours ago, the system crashed.
- I restarted and, now, interfaces are found.
- No explanation. This was not the first restart since the trouble.
- My question is outdated.